# TypeError: TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]

Tags: dataset, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to create tokens for the dataset loaded from huggingface repo. But while creating the repos it is showing the error:
TypeError: TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]

1. the dataset is created in the huggibface repo by creating train.csv and test.csv
2. load the dataset from the repo
3. try to create the tokens

```
 

    #1.created a dataset in hugging face by uploading csv files :

    df=nlp_df_subset[['topic','text_cleaned']]

    df=nlp_df_subset[['topic','text_cleaned']]
    df1=df[:8000]
    df1=df[8000:]
    df1.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/colab_data/train.csv')
    df2.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/colab_data/test.csv')

    #2. read the dataset from huggingface repos

   #loading the dataset
   model_checkpoint = "t5-small"
   raw_datasets_billsum = load_dataset("xsum")
   data_files = {"train": "train.csv", "test": "test.csv"}

   raw_datasets = load_dataset("lokesh8185/articlesTOPICextraction",data_files=data_files)
   metric = load_metric("rouge")
   
   structure of the dataset:
   DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['Unnamed: 0', 'topic', 'text_cleaned'],
        num_rows: 8000
      })
     test: Dataset({
        features: ['Unnamed: 0', 'topic', 'text_cleaned'],
        num_rows: 2000
    })
})


#3. create the tokens for topic(label) and text_cleaned(input):


max_input_length = 1024
max_target_length = 128

def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = [prefix + doc for doc in examples["text_cleaned"]]#summary
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_input_length, truncation=True)

    # Setup the tokenizer for targets
    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        labels = tokenizer(examples["topic"], max_length=max_target_length, truncation=True)
        #print(labels)
   
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs
tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(prepr`ocess_function, batched=True) #error here.
```